# Expected an identifier and instead saw '>'

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jshint

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Please let me know why VSCode `[jshint]` showed that issue? And please also let me know how to add some code inside `.jshintrc`

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JSHint does not support linting of `jsx`. If you want to develop react applications using `jsx` you should disable it or better switch to [ESLint](https://eslint.org/).

For Visual Studio Code there is [a plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) that you can install.

Answer (score 3):

Press ⇧⌘X and then write there **jshint** and uninstall it.

After that write **eslint** and install it if not before.

And make sure your **"esversion":6** is 6 for that follow below flow

**For Mac VSCode** : Code(Left top corner) => Prefrences => Settings => USER SETTINGS.
and check at right side and write below Code

```
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
  "git.ignoreMissingGitWarning": true,
  "window.zoomLevel": 0,
  // you want to write below code for that
  "jshint.options": {
      "esversion":6
  },
}
```

Comment: If you uninstall jshint package, the "jshint.options" would not take any affect I think.

Answer (score -1):

If you have already installed jshint in VS code & gives errors in your react app, then you can disable the jshint extension & it will fix all the issues.