# Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'. React.js Project

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm creating a simple e-commerce React project to learn, I'm using Visual Studio. However, I got these errors:

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC2EP.png)

My index.js code is

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVM0X.png)

Thanks

Comment: It would be best if you placed your code here as code rather than as an image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your file structure is but when you initialize a React project 'App.js' and 'index.js' should be in your root directory. Then you would import App as `import App from './App';`

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this question: [Expected an identifier and instead saw '>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50229573/expected-an-identifier-and-instead-saw)

"JSHint does not support linting of jsx. If you want to develop react applications using jsx you should disable it or better switch to ESLint.

For Visual Studio Code there is a plugin that you can install."

In your Settings > User Settings, add this if it's not already there.

```
"jshint.options": {
      "esversion":6
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error will occur if JSX is not being compiled properly. See Example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script>
  function App() {
    return (
      <div>Sample Component</div>
    );
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
</script>
```

**To solve this**, use technologies such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to enable JSX syntax

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
  function App() {
    return (
      <div>Sample Component</div>
    );
  }

  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
</script>
```